# Open 5000 port on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, port, digital-ocean, firewall, ufw

i have enabled port 5000 using ufw and it shows as below.

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5000/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5000 on eth0               ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5000/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5000 (v6) on eth0          ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But i can not connect using that port.

this is a droplet hosted on digitalocean.

NOTE:- i have disabled firewall from digitalocean panel.

Comment: What protocol are you trying EG `SSH`?  --  You will most likely have to set the port up in your "server" --  Whatever you are "serving" IE `SSH` - `HTTP` - `FTP` etc etc etc ..

Comment: hi @Zak the port is up in the server.                                                                              tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN      14166/osrm-routed

Comment: *"But i can not connect using that port."* --  Again, I ask cannot connect **how**?  SSH?  The port my be up, and the machine itself may be listening ..  But HOW YOU ARE TRYING TO CONNECT might be refusing the connection .. IE `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you would have to se the port as well if that's how you are trying to connect ..